# Syntax error when selecting column 'Comment' in Sybase IQ

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I have a table A with some columns in Sybase IQ. One of the columns is named "Comment".

Whenever I select that column:

```
select Comment from A
```

I got the error:

```
[Error Code: 102, SQL State: 42W04]  SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'Comment'
```

I am able to select other columns without issues. Could you advise the reason and solution? Thank you

Comment: If ever you encounter a situation where one name seems to be treated differently from others that otherwise seem identical, your first instinct should always be to search for the [reserved words in whatever language you're using](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Alhakeywords.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select "Comment" from A
```

[COMMENT is a reserved word](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315695.htm) in Sybase IQ.

Here is [the link explaining your problem](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Alhakeywords.htm).

> Some keywords in SQL are also reserved words. To use a reserved word
>   in a SQL statement as an identifier, you must enclose the word in
>   double quotes. Many, but not all, of the keywords that appear in SQL
>   statements are reserved words. For example, you must use the following
>   syntax to retrieve the contents of a table named SELECT.
>
> SELECT *  FROM "SELECT"